# execute local bash script in remote machine using expect

Tags: 12.04, server, bash, scripts, expect

I have local shell script. Now, I want to run this local script in remote machine. Of course I can use `ssh`, but as it(the local shell script) should be like an automated one, it shouldn't ask for password to enter manually. So I used expect to eliminate that problem, so that if I run the script it wont ask password. And my script looks like below.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no root@10.3.0.39 'bash -s' < /path/to/localscript
expect -timeout 7 "*(yes/no)?" { send "yes\r";exp_continue } 
expect -timeout 3 "*d: "
send "qbcrootpass\n"
interact
```

But it is not working. Please note, in my scenario, I don't want to use public key authentication.

Please help me to execute a local script in a remote machine using using expect.

Comment: How would you authenticate with neither the public key not the password?

Comment: @Jobin The password is being sent by the expect script above.

Comment: I hope you are aware that this is much less safe than using a public key. Just in case you were doing this for security.

Comment: Hi terdon, I know this is less secure. But I need this in my scenario.

Answer (score 2):

That redirection is processed by your shell at the command line. Expect won't understand how to do it. This should work (untested):

```
set fh [open /path/to/localscript r]
set contents [read $fh]
close $fh

spawn ssh ... "bash -c '$contents'"
```

Comment: bah, there are quoting issues there ("there be dragons..."). Let us know how you get on.

Comment: Your approach here might be a better one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14044575/12870

Comment: Hi glenn, now it just displays the external script while running this.